# Cathing flask abort status code within a test_request_context

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I want to understand how I can catch an `HTTPException` raised by `flask.abort` while using a `test_request_context` in a test for the calling method only.

```py
# example.py
import flask

@api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def do_stuff():
    param_a = get_param()
    return jsonify(a=param_a)

# check if request is json, return http error codes otherwise
def get_param():
    if flask.request.is_json():
        try:
           data = flask.request.get_json()
           a = data('param_a')
        except(ValueError):
            abort(400)
    else:
        abort(405)


# test_example.py
from app import app  # where app = Flask(__name__)
from example import get_param
import flask

def test_get_param(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data=flask.json.dumps(good_json), content_type='application/json'):
        assert a == get_param()
```

In the `get_param` method above, I try to `abort` if the `is_json()` or the `get_json()` fail. To test this, I pass `test_request_context` without a `content_type` and, based on this [blog](https://dev.to/wangonya/asserting-exceptions-with-pytest-8hl) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356706/6003691), I tried adding a nested context manager like so:

```py
# test_example.py
from app import app  # where app = Flask(__name__)
from example import get_param
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
import flask

def test_get_param_aborts(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data=flask.json.dumps('http://example', 'nope'), content_type=''):
        with pytest.raises(HTTPException) as httperror:
            get_param()
            assert 405 == httperror
```

but I get a `assert 405 == <ExceptionInfo for raises contextmanager>` assertion error.

Can someone please explain this and suggest a way to test the `abort` in this `get_param` method?

**Update:**
Based on @tmt's answer, I modified the test. However, even though the test passes, while debugging I notice that the two assertions are never reached!

```py
# test_example.py
from app import app  # where app = Flask(__name__)
from example import get_param
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
import flask

def test_get_param_aborts(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data=flask.json.dumps('http://example', 'nope'), content_type=''):
        with pytest.raises(HTTPException) as httperror:
            get_param()  # <-- this line is reached
            assert 405 == httperror.value.code
            assert 1 ==2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httperror` is an instance of [ExceptionInfo](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#exceptioninfo) which is pytest's own class that describes the exception. Once it happens, `httperror` would also contain `value` property which would be the instance of the `HTTPException` itself. If my memory is correct `HTTPException` contains `code` property that equals to the HTTP status code so you can use it to do the assertion:

```py
# test_example.py
from app import app
from example import get_param
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
import flask

def test_get_param_aborts(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data=flask.json.dumps(), content_type=''):
        with pytest.raises(HTTPException) as httperror:
            get_param()

        assert 405 == httperror.value.code
```

**Notes**:

- `get_param()` needs to be called within `pytest.raises()` context manager.
- The assertion needs to be done outside of the context manager because once an exception is raised the context ends.
- I don't know if `pytest.raise` is your typo or if it really existed in older versions of pytest. AFAIK it should be [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#id20).

Comment: Thank you for your answer (see my update). But it still does not work since the assertions are never reached ... Have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, see my notes. You cannot have the assertions within the last context manager.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up: could you please explain with the assetion cannot be within the 2nd context manager? Also, if I were to pass the output of the `get_param()` into a variable and assert that this is `None`, where should I put that assert? Outside the 2nd context manager gives an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'content' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: As soon as an exception is encountered, the `pytest.raises()` context manager ends and any assertions within it would not be executed and that's why you would need to put hem outside. Also, you cannot save the output of `get_param()` into any variable because there is not going to be any output if an exception happens.